# HTML Doc Type and Char set by Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a project at which it is needed to get doctype and char-set.

The fact is I get it by another way. But it is so difficult to get the doctype and char-set by regular expression as this can be told in html in various way.

So can anybody help me on getting this.

I need to get all the text after `<!DOCTYPE` from `<!DOCTYPE HTML or more can be here>` and the `char-set` value from `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` .

I want to use it in `PHP` `preg_match` function. So if anybody help me in that case it will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Given something like this:

> `<!DOCTYPE HTML or more can be here>`

To capture what follows **`<!DOCTYPE`**, the Regex search string **`(pattern)`** should be:

> `<!DOCTYPE[ ]+([^ ][^>]+[^ />]+)[ /]*>`

The (first) back-reference (**`\1`**) will hold the value of everything following **`<!DOCTYPE`**, but will not include any trailing "" (**`spaces`**), "**`/`**" (**`slashes`**), or "**`>`**" (**`right-angle-brackets`**).

So, for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN">
```

it will return this:

```
HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN"
```

---

**`charset`** is a little more difficult. It can be in one of these 2 forms:

1. Short:
   `<meta charset='utf-8'>`
2. Long:
   `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>`

To capture the value for **`charset`**, the Regex search string should be:

```
<meta[ ]+([^>]*|)(charset=['" ]*([^'"> ][^'">]+[^'"> ])['" ]*|charset=[ ]*([^'"> ][^'">]+[^'"> ]))([^>]*|)>
```

The third back-reference (**`\3`**) will hold the value for **`charset`**,  and will not include any leading or trailing
**`" "`** (**`spaces`**), or [**`'"`**] (**`quote-marks`**), or "**`>`**" (**`right-angle-brackets`**).

So, for any like these (some are not proper but may be encountered):

```
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta charset='utf-8 '>
<meta charset=" utf-8">
<meta charset=" utf-8 ">

<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta charset='utf-8' something='value'>
<meta something='value' charset="utf-8">
<meta something='value' charset='utf-8 ' somethingelse='value'>

<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content=text/html; charset=utf-8>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' >
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8 ' >
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset= utf-8' >
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset= utf-8 ' >

<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content=text/html; charset=utf-8>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' something='value'>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' something='value' content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta something='value' http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' >
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' something='value' content='text/html; charset=utf-8 ' something='value' >
```

it will return:

```
utf-8
```

---

**Note:** There has been a correction to the **`pattern`** string above for matching ***DOCTYPE*** (an **`"*"`** (asterisk) was out of place).

---

**Edit:**

How to use the Regex search strings **`(patterns)`** above using the  **`PHP`** function: **`preg_match`**...

The syntax of **`preg_match`** (from [function.preg-match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)):

```
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches)
```

> ***pattern***: The pattern to search for, as a string.
>      ***subject***: The input string.
>      ***matches***: If ***matches*** is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. ***$matches[0]*** will contain the text that matched the full pattern, ***$matches[1]*** will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

The **`pattern`** has to be enclosed in **`delimiters`** so **`preg_match`** can tell which part of the string is the **`Regex-pattern-string`**, and which part is the **`<pattern-modifiers>`** ([see this about delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)).  (Note: **`subject`** does not need **`delimiters`**).

The **`pattern`** string is composed like this:

> ***`<opening-delimiter>`***`Regex-pattern-string`***`<closing-delimiter>`*** ***`<pattern-modifiers>`***

Typically, you would use a **`"/"`** for the **`delimiters`**, but you can use most forms of **`brackets`**, or (most) any **`punctuation`** (non alphanumerics).

In this case, you are using a **`"/"`** within the **`pattern`** string, so for this example, we will use a **`"#"`** as the delimiter to make it easier.

For this example, we will also use a **`pattern-modifier`** of **`i`**. This specifies that the search will be performed without regard for the **`case`** of the characters in the **`pattern`** or the **`subject`**. You could also include an additional **`pattern-modifier`** of **`m`** 
to specify that **`newline`** **`("\n")`** is treated as a normal character in the **`subject`** string. This is useful if the text in the **`subject`** string might span multiple lines.

So, for the first case, the **`PHP`** code would look something like this:

```
$pattern="#<!DOCTYPE[ ]+([^ ][^>]+[^ />]+)[ /]*>#i";
$subject="<!DOCTYPE HTML or more can be here>";
$result=preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches)
/* if $result===1, then a match was found */
/* and the captured text can be found in $matches[1] */
```

Specifying the **`pattern`** string for the second case is a little more complicated, because it contains both **`(')`** (single-quotes) and **`(")`** (double-quotes).

Quote-marks are not actually an issue inside the **`pattern`** string because **`preg_match`** treats quote-marks like any other character. The issue with quote-marks here is in writing the PHP code that defines the string containing the **`pattern`**.

So, in order to define the string, you have to **`escape`** either the **`(')`** (single-quotes) or **`(")`** (double-quotes).

There are three choices:

1. Define the **`pattern`** string by surrounding it with **`(")`** (double-quotes), and then **`escape`** each of the **`(")`** (double-quotes) in the string by preceding them with a **`(\)`** (backslash).
2. Define the **`pattern`** string by surrounding it with **`(')`** (single-quotes), and then **`escape`** each of the **`(')`** (single-quotes) in the string by preceding them with a **`(\)`** (backslash).
3. Define the **`pattern`** string by surrounding it with **`(")`** (double-quotes), and then specify each of the **`(")`** (double-quotes) in the string using the **`HEX`** representation: **`\x22`**.

So, you can define the **`pattern`** string in one of these three ways:

```
$pattern='#<meta[ ]+([^>]*|)(charset=[\'" ]*([^\'"> ][^\'">]+[^\'"> ])[\'" ]*|charset=[ ]*([^\'"> ][^\'">]+[^\'"> ]))([^>]*|)>#i';
$pattern="#<meta[ ]+([^>]*|)(charset=['\" ]*([^'\"> ][^'\">]+[^'\"> ])['\" ]*|charset=[ ]*([^'\"> ][^'\">]+[^'\"> ]))([^>]*|)>#i";
$pattern="#<meta[ ]+([^>]*|)(charset=['\x22 ]*([^'\x22> ][^'\x22>]+[^'\x22> ])['\x22 ]*|charset=[ ]*([^'\x22> ][^'\x22>]+[^'\x22> ]))([^>]*|)>#i";
```

For the second case, the **`PHP`** code would look something like this:

```
$pattern='#<meta[ ]+([^>]*|)(charset=[\'" ]*([^\'"> ][^\'">]+[^\'"> ])[\'" ]*|charset=[ ]*([^\'"> ][^\'">]+[^\'"> ]))([^>]*|)>#i';
$subject="<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>";
$result=preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches)
/* if $result===1, then a match was found */
/* and the captured text can be found in $matches[3] */
```

Comment: Kevin Fegan thanks for your answer. But unfortunately I cannot works with your regular expression with PHP `preg_match()` function as it is showing this :

`Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier ']' in pattern`

for both of the regular expression I get this message. Can you help me in this case??

Comment: @Razin223 - I believe the warning you received was because you probably didn't provide the proper **`delimiters`** in the **`pattern`** string for the **`preg_match()`** function.  I have added some additional information and sample code to my answer.

Comment: @Razin223 - If this answer worked for you you can mark it as accepted so others know this solution worked. If not, let me know and I'll have be glad to continue to help you.